# JavaScriptでクッキーやキャッシュ等を削除するボタンを実装したい

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data

`Clear-Site-Data` を使ってキャッシュを削除するボタンを置きたいのですが、
headerの指定の仕方が間違っているのか、うまくいきません。

どのように設定すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: なにでどのように指定していて、どううまくいなかいとのですか？できれば実コードで示してください。

Comment: あとCookieはCacheではありません

Comment: `async fetch("/", headers{ "Clear-Site-Data": "*" })` このような感じでしたいのですが。。。

Comment: 確かに、CookieはCacheではありませんでした><すみません。

Answer (score 1):

> `async fetch("/", headers{ "Clear-Site-Data": "*" })` このような感じでしたいのですが。。。

とのことですが，当該のヘッダーはMDNの上のほうにもあるようにリクエストヘッダーではなく**レスポンスヘッダー**，すなわちサーバー側で指定するものです．当然ながらリクエストヘッダーにそれを指定したところで機能しません．

**もし**，動的にヘッダーを指定できないサーバー環境を利用している場合であれば別の手段を講じる必要があるかもしれません．

Answer (score 0):

部分回答になりますが、クッキーに関しては **有効期限を現在時刻より過去の値に設定** すれば削除されます。